# Time calculation with negative value results Java

Tags: java, time

I want to calculate the difference between a start time and an end time. In `HH:mm` format.

I receive a negative value when, for example, the start time is `22.00` and the end time is `1.00` the next day.

How do I let the program know the end time is on the next day?

My script:

```
public void setBeginTijd()
{
    String dateStart = "22:00";
    String dateEnd = "1:00";

    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");

    Date d1 = null;
    Date d2 = null;

    try
    {
        d1 = format.parse(dateStart);
        d2 = format.parse(dateEnd);

        long diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();
        long diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000) % 60;
        long diffHours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000) % 24;

        System.out.println(diffMinutes);
        System.out.println(diffHours);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: As per me, there is no way the program will know that 1:00 is next day, unless you specify the date. So your method must accept the DateTime object instead of just Time object

Comment: You must use full date instead of hour and minutes. Otherwise how can you recognize the day?

Comment: Where do you get the time values from anyway? Do you read them out of a log or a database? Or are they from somewhere in your program? If it's possible for you to use a time stamp or a _full_ `Date` object instead, it would give you much greater precision.

Comment: The time values come from a methods parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned by some people, it is important to also know day, month and year of each event to calculate periods for events that are not on the same day.

I modified your method the way I think it could help you:

```
public void setBeginTijd()
{
        String dateStart = "22.08.2014 22:00";
        String dateEnd = "25.08.2014 01:00";

        SimpleDateFormat fullFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm");

        Date d1 = null;
        Date d2 = null;

        try
        {
            d1 = fullFormat.parse(dateStart);
            d2 = fullFormat.parse(dateEnd);

            long diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();
            long diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000) % 60;
            long diffHours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000) % 24;
            long diffDays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

            System.out.println("Delta minutes: " + diffMinutes);
            System.out.println("Delta hours: " + diffHours);
            System.out.println("Delta days: " + diffDays);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is very helpfull. I realise now that I need to use a date as well.

Answer (score 6):

If you can **assume** that, when the time is negative, the second time must be on the next day, then you can simply say

```
if (diff < 0)
{
    diff = (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) + diff;
}
```

---

EDIT to elaborate this, also in response to the comments: Of course this is a very simplistic solution. It can not handle the case where the second date is two days later. It does not handle DST switches. It does not handle the [time zone change on December 31st, 1927 in Shanghai](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6841333/3182664). It is no replacement for a properly modelled date with all its caveats. It is a best-effort approach to derive what can (probably) be derived from the given information.

Comment: This is neat (y). But I think if day difference is more than one day Then  this will not work

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    SimpleDateFormat formatNextDay = new SimpleDateFormat("dd:HH:mm");
    boolean isNextDay=false;
    try {
        if (d1.after(d2)) {
            isNextDay=true; 
            d1 = formatNextDay.parse("1:" + dateStart);
            d2 = formatNextDay.parse("2:" + dateEnd);
        }
```

Comment: Just solving the problem for the next day case isn't a good advice. It is very likely that further issues will appear when dates with more than one day in between are entered. By the way, the variable `isNextDay` is totally useless.

Answer (score 0):

You should include day, month and year in date.

This are dates in Java after ran program:

```
d1 = Thu Jan 01 22:00:00 CET 1970
d2 = Thu Jan 01 01:00:00 CET 1970
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct math for time difference in hours & minutes. Stripping of the decimal fraction is happening automatically when you operate on int/long values.

```
long diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();
long diffHours = diff / 1000 / 60 / 60;
long diffMinutes = diff / 1000 / 60 - diffHours * 60;
```